# Angular2: is there a way to set an input as pristine, by accessing its $event?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form on which I can access its controllers. I can run the `markAsPristine` method over it.

I can execute `this.form.controls.password.markAsPristine();` and all working perfect for me.

The thing is that I want to `markAsPristine` the input directly when I receive it by an `$event`. Meaning something like that:

```
<input 
    [formControl]="password" 
    type="password" class="form-control 
    (input)="checkIfPasswordIsEmpty($event)">

checkIfPasswordIsEmpty(event): void {
    if (event.currentTarget.value === '') {
        this.form.controls.password.markAsPristine();
    }
}
```

Right now, I'm marking the input as pristine by accessing it directly inside the controls object. I wish to avoid calling it specifically, and access it by the `$event` I receive from the method `checkIfPasswordIsEmpty($event)`.

Does this kind of option exist?

Answer (score 0):

You can use control directive to achieve this. Here is how I did Angular 4, and I believe be similar in 2.

In Template:
    #password="ngModel"

In Component: 
    `export class SomeComponent {
        @ViewChild('password')
        password: NgModel;`

In function that makes pristine: 
     `this.password.reset()`

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you would like to use `checkIfPasswordIsEmpty()` on more that one input and inside check which one of the inputs fired it. I would achieve it as bellow:

**HTML**

```
 <input id="password"
    formControlName="password" #password
    type="password" class="form-control" 
    (input)="checkIfPasswordIsEmpty($event)">
```

**Typescript**

```
   checkIfPasswordIsEmpty(event): void {
      let field = (event.srcElement.attributes[2].value); // get which input fired this method
      let value = this.user.get(field).value; // get its value
      if (!value) {
          this.user.get(field).markAsPristine(); //set it pristine
      }
   }
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e9y5k5?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: what is 'control' ?